# Can you use regular knife sharpeners on damascus steel?

Tags: knives, utensils

Can you use regular knife sharpeners on  damascus steel?

I'm aware it should be sharpened properly once a month on a wet stone, but I want to know if I should keep it bright by using a steel between uses?

Is there anything else to bear in mind? I was thinking of getting a [little gadget](https://www.lakeland.co.uk/71074/AnySharp-Knife-Sharpener?src=gfeed&ef_id=CjwKCAiAuqHwBRAQEiwAD-zr3Xf4Krsk8hoq-I2B-NAfVTWjnEeWBrpeIEgM5eLHCtD6A1p_CI2s_BoCxgYQAvD_BwE:G:s&s_kwcid=AL!49!3!398465063207!!!g!300333215220!&gclid=CjwKCAiAuqHwBRAQEiwAD-zr3Xf4Krsk8hoq-I2B-NAfVTWjnEeWBrpeIEgM5eLHCtD6A1p_CI2s_BoCxgYQAvD_BwE) which was recommended, but I don't know if it can be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, you can use a honing steel with a damascus-style carbon steel knife blade.  Depending on what you have, you may need to get a harder honing steel, because the carbon steel of the knife is harder than a stainless blade.  I have a [honing steel from Shun](https://shun.kaiusaltd.com/knives/knife/classic-combination-honing-steel) that works quite well.
2. Do NOT use that "Anysharp" sharpener or any sharpener like it.  Such sharpeners are designed to sharpen blades by aggressively removing metal from the blade edge.  If you use one of them, you can expect to wear down the edge of your blade and use up the hard steel there in just a few years.

NOTE: Many "Damascus" blades sold commercially aren't actually Damascus-style, that is, folded carbon steel.  Instead, they are stainless or standard carbon steel with two face plates of folded steel on either side of the blade, purely for decorative purposes.  These blades have the same care instructions as any stainless or carbon blade.

Answer (score -1):

Damascus steel was carbon steel with non-uniform carbon content (to give ripple pattern).  It would be sharpened the same as any other steel knife. I don't know how a knife made today with the name "Damascus" is made. For my ordinary stainless ( typically 420 = 13% Cr ) I usually just use the wet stone and don't bother with the steel.